# How to access a selected Boundfield value from a GridView in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind, readonly

I have seen similar questions but none of the answers helped me to workout this problem.
I have GridView with a ReadOnly field as follow.

**GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="projectID" 
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." 
              PageSize="5" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
  <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="prID" HeaderText="prID" SortExpression="prID"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="projectName" HeaderText="projectName" 
                    SortExpression="projectName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="projectType" HeaderText="projectType" 
                    SortExpression="projectType" />
  </Columns>
  <EditRowStyle CssClass="GridViewEditRow"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

as you can see the `prID` BoundField has `Readonly=True` attribute.
I'm trying to get the value of the `prID` in code-behind when user is updating the other fields in the row.

**code-behind:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    String d1 = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    String d2 = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;

    // this only works while the field is not readonly      
    string prIDUpdate = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text; 

}
```

**Note:** I have tried using `GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]` and also `onRowDataBound` an d setting the BoundField ready only in code-behind but I haven't been able to get results

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I saw that your DataKeyNames setting in **GridView control** is like this

```
DataKeyNames="projectID"
```

Then I guess that your key name is **projectID** not **prID**, isn't it?
If so, you could get data for the selected row as this line:

```
string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["projectID"].ToString();
```

And you should also add this column:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="projectID" HeaderText="prID" SortExpression="projectID"/>
```

Did you try that?

In other way, you could try to use TemplateField instead

```
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="prID" SortExpression="prID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("prID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="projectName" HeaderText="projectName" 
                    SortExpression="projectName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="projectType" HeaderText="projectType" 
                    SortExpression="projectType" />
  </Columns>
```

And this code to get data from prID column in GridView1_RowUpdating event handler:

```
Label lblPrId = row.FindControl("lblPrId") as Label;    
string prId = lblPrId .Text;
```

Sorry if this doesn't help.